# Debugging a slow Java method

Tags: java, performance, visualvm

VisualVM is showing me that a particular method is taking a long time to execute.

Are there any widely used strategies for looking at the performance (in regards to time) of a Java method?

My gut feeling is that the sluggish response time will come from a method that is somewhere down the call hierarchy from the one VisualVM is reporting but I think getting some hard numbers is better than fishing around in the code based on an assumption when it comes to performance.

Comment: VisualVM organizes times not by method, but by complete call stack, so you can always drill down to exactly the method call that makes its callers consume time.

Answer (score 2):

VisualVM should be showing you the methods which use the most CPU. If the biggest user is your method, it means it not a method you are calling unless you are calling many methods which individually look small but in total are more.

I suggest you take the difference of the methods this method calls and your total. That is how much your method is adding which being profiled. Note: how much it adds when not profiled could be less as the profiler has an overhead.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the comment but I'm not entirely sure what you mean in regards to " methods which individually look small but in total are more" and "I suggest you take the difference of the methods this method calls and your total".

Comment: The time spent in a method can include all the methods its calls as well. If methodA calls methodB and methodC and these take 10 seconds, 2 seconds and 3 seconds, the methodA is adding 10 - 2 - 3 = 5 seconds.

Comment: The sum of all the methods execution times is the metric I am using.

Comment: In that case, you are assuming only the method you call are using CPU. Can you optimise those methods or call them less?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use tools like JProfiler, Yourkit etc. You can profile you code in depth & you can exactly catch which method is taking much time. You can go as much in depth hierarchy as you want with these tools.